# postgresql json date format issue

Tags: json, ajax, postgresql

I am having issues with my postgresql dates. I a column with type `date`. An example value in the column is `2016-01-28`. However, when I make an AJAX request to retrieve data from the server, the date is returned as `"2016-01-28T07:18:01.000Z"`.  Does anyone know why the additional `T07:18:01.000Z` is there and how I can prevent it?

The only workaround I know is to use the `dateformat` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) to parse the date once it is returned from the AJAX request - but i'd rather not do it if I can return the date without the additional `T07:18:01.000Z`.

Here is my query:

```
knex('reports')
.where({
    projectid: req.params.id
})
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data[0].start_date //returns "2016-01-28T07:18:01.000Z"
    res.send(data)
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the SQL query that retrieves the data and the code that generates the JSON. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i updated my question w/ my query using the Knex ORM. I am using node.js